# How to schedule a task to run regularly in iron.io

Tags: ironworker, iron

I have a worker which is up and running without errors. I would like to schedule tasks to run every morning at 9.30 using the CLI. Documentation is  a little confusing when it comes to scheduling regular tasks using CLI. What I would try is joining `iron_worker schedule worker --start-at "2014-07-22T09:30:00-04:00"` and `iron_worker schedule worker --run-every 1440` commands somehow. By the way what does the `4:00` at the end of the first command mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iron_worker schedule --help` is good reading ;)

I think command would looks like

```
iron_worker schedule code_name --start-at "2014-07-22T09:30:00-04:00" --run-every 86400
```

where "-04:00" is timezone,

86400 - interval between executions (24 * 60 * 60 seconds = 1 day)

Also, you could use UI - http://hud.iron.io/ -> project -> Scheduled Tasks to create new schedule

Comment: When I try it and it works I will accept your answer